# Statistics Review

Tags: statistics

The class of 2015 at a college, with a graduation rate of 60%, has 250 students. What is the probability that:

1) all the student will graduate in four years?

2) half of the students will graduate in four years?

3) exactly 75% of the students will graduate in four years?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?  (1) is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm new to this but if it is as easy I thought it is, then for one student (1/250) to graduate its: (1/250)*60%, right? Then for all students, then (250/250)*60%; for half (125/250)*60%; and for the last is: (x/250)*60% = 75% where i solve for x ?

Comment: Not quite, no - I'll post an answer.  Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The odds of any one student graduating is $0.6$.  When you need to "and" together the probabilities of two (independent) events - for example, *Alice graduates AND Bob graduates* - you multiply.  So the probability that two given students both graduate is equal to $0.6^2$, and the probability that $250$ given students all graduate is $0.6^{250}$.  That's (1).

Here's a question: what is the probability that $k$ students graduate, and the remaining $250-k$ students don't?  For each possible set of $k$ students, we're going to need to find the probability that they graduate and their peers don't, *and then add this probability up over all possible sets*.  The probability for any one set is $0.6^k 0.4^{1-k}$ (do you see why?  It's the same multiplication trick as before).  The number of sets is just $250 \, C \, k$ - are you familiar with "choose" combinatorics?  Anyways, maybe that will be enough of a hint to get (2).

I'm a little confused by (3).  Exactly $75\%$ of $250$ is $187.5$, and you're not going to have half a student graduating.  Maybe the answer is $0$?  Maybe they mean exactly $188$ students graduating?  Your call.